# Combine Mp4s using mp4parser on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, mp4, mp4parser

I was just wondering if anybody knows how to take an mp4 audio file and overlay it onto an mp4 video file using `mp4parser` on Android. I have been able to append one video with another, now I just need to overlay a raw mp4 that I have over the combined file.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code muxes two audio languages and a video. It should be easy to adopt it to your needs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String audioDeutsch = MuxMp4SourcesExample.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile() + "/count-deutsch-audio.mp4";
    String audioEnglish = MuxMp4SourcesExample.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile() + "/count-english-audio.mp4";
    String video = MuxMp4SourcesExample.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile() + "/count-video.mp4";


    Movie countVideo = MovieCreator.build(new FileInputStream(video).getChannel());
    Movie countAudioDeutsch = MovieCreator.build(new FileInputStream(audioDeutsch).getChannel());
    Movie countAudioEnglish = MovieCreator.build(new FileInputStream(audioEnglish).getChannel());

    Track audioTrackDeutsch = countAudioDeutsch.getTracks().get(0);
    audioTrackDeutsch.getTrackMetaData().setLanguage("deu");
    Track audioTrackEnglish = countAudioEnglish.getTracks().get(0);
    audioTrackEnglish.getTrackMetaData().setLanguage("eng");

    countVideo.addTrack(audioTrackDeutsch);
    countVideo.addTrack(audioTrackEnglish);

    Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(countVideo);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.mp4"));
    out.writeContainer(fos.getChannel());
    fos.close();

}
```

Comment: Audio Is overwriting when using this code.. ANy help ??

Comment: @Sebastian The audio tracks are added one after the other . Is there anyway I can add  two audio tracks and they have to run at the same time and obviously the video. Let's say I have a video and a voice audio and also a background music. Now I want to have these two audio run parallely at the same time with the video. Can you help how we can achieve this ?

Comment: Above mentioned code mixes the video with the first audio track added. I want to play two audio track parallel with video file. Can anyone help me for that

Comment: @SebastainAnnies Is it possible to combine two video files into one using `mp4parser` in java